# No podspec found for `RNPDF` in `../node_modules/react-native-view-pdf`

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, podfile, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am creating Azure build pipeline for react native app and in that while installing pods using cocoapod task that is:

```
- task: CocoaPods@0
  inputs:
    forceRepoUpdate: true
    projectDirectory: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/ios'
  displayName: 'pod install using the CocoaPods'
```

I get this error on running the pipeline:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod --version
1.9.1
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod install --repo-update --project-directory=/Users/runner/runners/2.166.2/work/1/s/ios
Updating local specs repositories
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
Analyzing dependencies
[!] No podspec found for `RNPDF` in `../node_modules/react-native-view-pdf`

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `abcd` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
##[error]The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod' failed with exit code 1
##[error]The 'pod' command failed with error: The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/pod' failed with exit code 1
```

I am unable to find the cause for this error, so need some help with this.
My podfile is like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'abcd' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for abcd
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging' 
 pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'

 pod 'RNPDF', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-view-pdf'

 pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

 pod 'react-native-pdf', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-pdf'


 target 'abcdTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
        end
end
```

If you need any other detail, please let me know in comments.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212255/discussion-on-question-by-rishav-singh-no-podspec-found-for-rnpdf-in-node).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the answer but i got a workaround,
i simply removed two lines:

```
pod 'RNPDF', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-view-pdf'
pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
```

from podfile, earlier it was like:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SiteFuelBuyer' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SiteFuelBuyer
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging' 
 pod 'RNPDF', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-view-pdf'
 pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'

 pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

 pod 'react-native-pdf', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-pdf'


 target 'SiteFuelBuyerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
        end
end
```

and now,

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SiteFuelBuyer' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SiteFuelBuyer
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging' 

 pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

 pod 'react-native-pdf', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-pdf'


 target 'SiteFuelBuyerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
        end
end
```

another better answers are always welcomed.